How to reference extern value in AsmJit
In AsmJit, how can I do the equivalent of this assembly:
extern g_value:dword
;...
add ecx, [g_value]

That is, reference an externally defined value.

From a quick browse of the documentation it looks like you can use Assembler::newNamedLabel with the kExternal label type.

It's something like this:
extern int gSomeInt;
// ...
x86::Assembler assembler(...);
// ...
assembler.mov(rdx, uintptr_t(&gSomeInt)); // Embed ptr value in jit code 
assembler.add(ecx, ptr(rdx));


x86 add allows a memory source operand so you should be able to do assembler.add(ecx, ptr(rdx));

Also, if your global variable is within +-2GiB of the machine code you're JITing, a RIP-relative addressing mode is possible.  Or if its in the low 2GiB of virtual address-space, a 32-bit absolute addressing mode is possible, like add ecx, [0x420000].  But you'd normally only have that for globals in the main executable of a Linux non-PIE executable.  Most distros configure GCC with -fPIE -pie as the default to allow ASLR.  And shared libraries are still at high addresses.

Cool. Just tried adding directly from rdx, and it worked like you said. Nice.

You can [edit] to improve your answer.
